# how to add a scanner to jtextfields

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input, jtextfield

I want to make a text based game  that reads certain input from the player and outputs the action in the jtextfield (Like scribblenauts). I know I should review jtextfields and jtextareas. But with my basic gui understanding do I do something like this for a Scanner for Textfields

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Ex. I have a text based rpg that starts outside or something. "A not is laid on the floor, Pick it up?" if the user types yes or no the system responds with "It is a letter from bob the builder!".

Then later on I want to let the user buy from the text shop. I can do all of this in the console but not In JTextfields.

Answer (score 3):

The key to solving your problem is to not do what you're trying to do: to shoe-horn a console type program into a GUI. They use different programming philosophies with the latter being event-based, and the former being linear. Solution: learn to code with the Swing tutorials, and put your Scanner to the side. You don't need it, nor do you want it.

Please check out:

- [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)
- [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

You use an `ActionListener` or a `InputVerifier` or a `DocumentListener` depending on when you want to be notified

See:

- [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)
- [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

For starters.

Remember a GUI is an event driven environment, something happens, you respond to it.  You program execution may not take the same path each time...